# Варианты реализации многопоточного сервера

Tags: c++, сервер, сокет

Есть видео-сервер, который принимает и раздаёт по запросу прямые трансляции с веб-камер и рабочих столов. Всё работает, но не долго. Такое ощущение, что что-то подвисает и после чего к серверу нельзя подключиться. Пропадает список стримеров в приложении для мониторинга и появляется только при перезапуске сервера.

Механизм приёма подключений реализован так:

```
while( true ){
    if( int accept_socket = accept(server_tcp_socket, NULL, NULL); )
        if( accept_socket!= -1 )
            std::thread(ConnectionHandler, accept_socket);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
}
```

В `ConnectionHandler` реализована обработка запросов клиента в цикле - `recv` -> обработали пакет и заново, пока `recv` не вернёт 0 или -1, после чего поток закрывается. При разрыве клиенты переподключаются. Мъютексы все проверил - везде всё разблокируется после доступа к общим ресурсам.

Интересно то, что на localhost сервер может висеть неделями и никогда проблем со стримами нет при 1-10 подключениях. Но в реальной системе, на удалённом адресе с каналом 100 мбит/с он работает ну полчаса от силы. Я конечно понимаю, что 60-80 мбит/с от 150 клиентов только в одну сторону могут ложить канал, но всё восстанавливается и "летает" после перезапуска сервера.
При обрыве связи WebSocket в веб-интерфейсе для просмотра стримов сообщает, что находится в состоянии `CONNECTING`, то есть пытается "достучаться", но никто не "открывает".

Проблему описал, что хочу спросить:

Является ли такой алгоритм приёма подключений корректным для подобной системы? Если нет как лучше сделать? Как понять причину зависания соединений?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::thread(ConnectionHandler, accept_socket);` это фейл. Создание потока на каждый запрос - само по себе безобразие, а тут у вас создается временные объект который сразу же уничтожается, а так как поток потенциально был еще joinable, то будет вызван `std::terminate`. Если обработка видео при отдаче не требуется, то все можно спокойно асинхронно раздавать из основного потока.

Comment: В обработчике подключений может производиться запись на диск. Если запись активирована, то обработчик держит открытым файл, чтобы не тратить время на его открытие каждый раз. Также подключения надо держать открытыми, а как это сделать из одного потока, я что-то не пойму

Comment: @Iceman А что мешает держать открытым соединение и файл из основного потока?

Comment: Файл один на каждого стримера. Подключений - 1 на каждого клиента, и много на различных наблюдателей. Можно конечно толкать это всё в списки, векторы... Ладно, подумаю над этим. А `accept` только новые подключения принимает или вообще все TCP пакеты?

Comment: @Iceman Только новые подключения.

Comment: Я тут случайно обнаружил, что `SOMAXCONN` задефайнен как 5 в `winsock.h` моего mingw-w64... Вот это, наверно, фейл... ))

Comment: @Iceman Это у вас видимо Winsock 1 30-летней давности подключен.

Comment: Переписал сервер на однопоточный с `select` - не выдерживает наплыва данных на реальном адресе - ничего не транслируется, в отличие от localhost с одним клиентом. Ещё какие варианты есть? По какому принципу тот же apache сделан?

Comment: @Iceman select - это конечно атавизм, но по идее для раздачи на 100 Мбит должно было  хватить. Наверное вы что-то намудрили в своем сервере. А вообще на windows имеет смыл использовать overlapped io для асинхронности.

Comment: В общем стримы пошли после игнорирования `WSAError 10035` на приёме (так как нужно получать только полные пакеты), но скорость конечно ужасная при таком объёме данных. Погуглил `overlapped io` - наткнулся на `IO Completion Port`. Буду его изучать. Спасибо за советы!